# Classpath for scope system vs provided

Tags: maven, maven-3

`system` and `provided` scope - both of them are similar but I wanted to know :

1) Is `system` scope means that dependency will included only in runtime classpath ?

2) How does classpath differ among the two ? Does `systempath` defined becomes the classpath for dependency of `system` scope ?

Since these are 2 short queries and tightly coupled  , hence not posting 2 questions for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system` means that the element will be added to the classpath verbatim (i.e. with absolute path) and that someone (admin, package manager) will have copied the JAR file to where `systempath` is pointing. Other dependencies are searched in the local Maven repository. Apart from that, it's like `provided`.

This kind of dependency should not be used. Ages ago, it was a simple way to add JARs to the classpath without installing them in the local Maven repo using `mvn file:install`.

`provided` means that it will somehow be on the classpath when the app runs. An example is an web container like Tomcat which brings a lot of the HTTP support classes like `Servlet`. Those classes security sensitive and need to match what the container was built with. So you have to tell Maven "please put it on the classpath for tests but not in the WAR, okay?".

See also:

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope
- https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies

Comment: Thnx for the answer . Just wanted to confirm -  system scope dependencies will be used in runtime classpath and not during compile time classpath ?

Comment: No, the other way around. They will be omitted like `provided` (at least according to the documentation) at runtime and available during compilation.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use system-scope for JARs, which I know, will be there? How does the ease of adding a copy of a JAR to the local Maven repository justify the additional space requirement implicit in creating such a copy?